# passing an object in ejs to a vue method

Tags: vue.js, ejs

in an  Express app, I need to pass an object to vue method, here is the ejs template:

```
 <%-item.price%>

 <button v-on:click="add_to(<%=item%>)" class="float-right">Add...</button>
```

here is the js:

```
  var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue!'
        },
        methods: {
            add_to: function (item) {
                console.log(item)
            }
        }
    })
```

but it does not work, any hint?  Thanks

Comment: Does rendering `<%=item%>` normally produce an `Object`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the ejs rendering the object you want to pass to the vue.js method with single quote `''`

```
v-on:click="add_to('<%=item%>')"
```